# Just installed UBUNTU and two problems

Tags: command-line, password

First every time it asks me for a password in a terminal all the keys on my keyboard stop working completely fine all the time until it asks for the terminal password so I cant do anything

Second. When it first booted up I was so happy my DVD drive which stopped working in Windows was suddenly cured and burned a few DVDs but now it doesn’t even show up anywhere

I'm completely new to this so type slowly

Comment: To your first question, it's by design, no asterisks means others won't know how long your password is, just type them in and hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

When the terminal asks for the password it is accepting keyboard input, it's not displaying the asterisks. Once you've entered the password press enter to proceed.

As for your disk drive going missing, you may have to insert a CD/DVD first before it appears in certain programs such as Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 0):

Password prompts on the terminal don't show what you're typing, this is a security feature. Just finish typing your password and then press enter and things should work.